# ggplot2: Dynamic legend title

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

In my code the titles for my legend were automatically generated (X1, X2, ...). How do I make it so instead of X#, it says "N = #" where n was given in my sapply function

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

PlotBinom <- function(p) {
  x <- c(0:500)
  df <- sapply(seq(50,500,by=50), function(n) dbinom(x,n,p))
  df <- data.frame(x,df)
  melted.df <- melt(df,id.vars='x')

  plot <- ggplot(melted.df,aes(x=x,y=value,colour=variable)) + geom_line() 

  print(plot)
}

PlotBinom(0.6)
PlotBinom(0.2)
```

Also, how do I change the legend symbol to go from a line to a full colored block? Here is what it is now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to `scale_colour_discrete` with a vector of desired labels...

```
PlotBinom <- function(p) {
  x <- c(0:500)
  df <- sapply(seq(50,500,by=50), function(n) dbinom(x,n,p))
  df <- data.frame(x,df)
  melted.df <- melt(df,id.vars='x')

  plot <- ggplot(melted.df,aes(x=x,y=value,colour=variable)) + geom_line()+
  scale_colour_discrete( labels= paste( "N =" ,1:length( unique(melted.df$variable) ) ) )

  print(plot)
}
```

[image]